# One time binding syntax for `ng-class` with array syntax and multiple classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this `ng-class` inside an `ng-repeat`, with array syntax. In the `ng-class` array, I am calling two functions in the controller `myCtrl` called `getClassFn1` and `getClassFn2`. The functions return two class names.

Here's how it looks like.

```
<div ng-repeat="(index, item) in myCtrl.menuItems track by item.myVar"
class="myClass"
ng-class="[myCtrl.getClassFn1(index), myCtrl.getClassFn2(item)]">
  ...
</div>
```

I want to know how I can apply one time binding to the `ng-class` array. I couldn't find anything from my research.

What I have tried :

1. `ng-class="::[myCtrl.getClassFn1(index), myCtrl.getClassFn2(item)]">`
2. `ng-class="::myCtrl.getClassFn1(index) + ' ' + ::myCtrl.getClassFn2(item)">`
3. `ng-class="[::myCtrl.getClassFn1(index), ::myCtrl.getClassFn2(item)]">`

None of these worked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it work without one-time binding?

Comment: As I understood, you want to bind just one function from both?

Comment: It works. But two-way binding cause my functions to be called so many times. @georgeawg

Comment: @FerhadOthman : I want to bind both

Comment: Your first example should work (I just tried it in a plunker - see here: https://plnkr.co/edit/7L1wA7yZqW5MaTmbZMCD)... What happens instead for you?

Comment: @james00794: I see. I was thinking, the reason why the getClass functions kept repeatedly called was because of the two-way binding. Thank you for confirming that the syntax for one time bound ng-class. There must be some other reason.

Comment: If you are changing some scope-bound variable in that function, your digest cycle will repeat over and over again, which will keep calling the function... but then you would see some errors in your console. It is usually better to bind to some controller variable instead of a function. Is there a reason you need it to be a function?

Comment: The functions only return the classes as strings. And yes, I want them to be functions because based on 'index' and 'item', the class returned changes. And the functions are used by multiple elements in the menu items.

Comment: OK - are there any console errors? How do you know that the functions are being called multiple times? Another thing - one-time binding in AngularJS will only "finish" after the return value is defined. So if there are a few digest cycles in which the return value from your functions are undefined, the one-time binding won't have come into effect yet, and the functions will keep being called, which is totally normal. That should stop once they bind to something other than undefined or null.

Comment: I have put something in the console.log and it gets printed infinitely. It must be the one time bind that keeps calling the function till a value is set. Thanks for your help. :)